# What do you call a function that returns same output as input?

Tags: function

I seem to remember there being a special name for a function whose output is always identical to its input, e.g.:

```
var whatsMyName = function (a) {
    return a;
};
```

Does anyone know what such a function -- which, in practice, is pretty pointless -- is called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's [the identity function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function)